# Using read_csv() on a matrix to create an adjacency matrix in igraph

Tags: r, matrix, igraph, readr

I have a matrix stored as a .csv file, in which column and row headers are identical (it's a citation matrix).

I use `read.csv()` to read the file and then I apply `as.matrix()` to transform the df into a matrix. I subsequently transform the matrix into a network with igraph's `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()`.

I cannot do this with readr's `read_csv()`. When I apply `graph_from_adjacency_matrix()` to the file read by `read_csv()` I end up with a non-square matrix which isn't what the function expects.

I *think* this is because `read_csv()` produces a tibble in which the very first column is labeled with readr's best guess for a column name (X1). An adjacency matrix does not need the first column in the matrix labeled (I think) and I am stumped about how to remove the first column header from only the very first row.

Can anyone explain how to get around this if I want to use `read_csv()` rather than `read.csv()`?

Comment: Kind of a puzzle since both `read.csv` and `readr::read_csv` assume that column names are present in the input file header. But we don't have any file or the code that was used.  If you need to change the default then the argument to use for `read_csv` is "col_names" rather tnan "col.names"

Comment: Does your csv have an actual column with the row names?

Comment: Yes, the first column contains row names--with the exception of the very first cell.

Comment: Then just Use `Adjacency = Adjacency[ , -1]`